# Why can't I make my ManagedBean properties getter and setter methods as static in jsf?

Tags: java, jsf

Its is giving HTTP Status 500 error
PropertyNotFoundException.
How ever if remove static from my getter and setters code executes all fine
please help me.

Answer (score 1):

When the variable is static that means that only one instance of a static field exists(Depending on the runtime characteristics, it can be one per ClassLoader or AppDomain or thread) even if you create a million instances of the class or you don't create any. It will be shared by all instances.

Static members can only refer to static members. Instance members can, however access static members.

Comment: Yeah, I got it!!I should make my properties static as well.Thanks